# Stylized installer for Windows App

Tags: .net, windows, installation

How I Can do installer with non-default front-end part like Visual Studio, Atom ?
[like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfNVn.png)

Answer (score 1):

Advanced Installer has a predefined theme looking like that. [Here's a screenshot.](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/surface-screen-shot.html)

I would assume there are tools that can help you get a similar installer UI, but I don't know of other that provide a built-in theme like the one linked above.